# Html5 File Input inside Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, popover

I'm trying to implement a note system where users can append notes to documents and upload files inside a popover
Unfortunately, when I click on the "Browse" button, the popup is closed. 
Is there anything I can do to prevent that?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, forget about it, I had another event (body click) that was being intercepted by the file input button.
I've fixed the issue.